# How to track the Data Lag b/w EventHub and Blob in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I'm working on Spark Streaming basically reading the near real-time data from EventHub and dumping onto Blob location, i will need to implement watermarking to see what is the delay(data lag) b/w the EventHub and the blob location. As we know EventHub holds only 2 days of data i will need to make sure there is no data loss b/w EventHub and the blob location. Is there a way i can achieve this in Spark structured streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve two things here

1.find the time lag .

2.find the data loss .

I suggest to atleast consider using Azure stream analytics for this . Its query language is very similar to SQL .